# why I am Getting Import error for eve.io.SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python-2.7, flask, sqlalchemy, eve

I am running the demo script available at

> https://gist.github.com/Tefnet/5430309

I am getting following error, despite having all libraries

flask sqlalchemy validate SQL

```
File demo.py in line 2 , in <module>
    from eve.io.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, Validator
ImportError no module named sqlalchemy
```

Not sure why is it giving ? even though I have installed EVE, SQLAlchemy, flask

Comment: Try `python -c "import sqlalchemy; print(sqlalchemy.__version__)"` in a terminal to see if `sqlalchemy` is indeed installed.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLAlchemy branch is a work in progress. It has evolved quite a bit from the fork linked by codegeek and now is almost on par (feature-wise) with v0.4dev.

- [Eve-SQLAlchemy branch](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/tree/sqlalchemy)

So if you want to play around with it, make sure to pull that branch. Also, one thing it's not been done yet is update `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`, so you will want to pip install sqlalchemy on your own.

You can find a rather complete Eve-SQL log by checking out [this very long lived ticket](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/17#issuecomment-40451071).

Comment: Even though I installed eve-SQLalchemy and seperately installed SQLAlchemy, the import module still throws error saying eve.io.sqlalchemy not present. But eve.io.SQL works. Could you clarify on that. Can I just call eve.io.SQL and use all api in SQLAlchemy ? Please clarify on that. I need to call sqllchemy separately.

Comment: Can you give test case for runnoing your example in SQL folder

Comment: Sir Nicola, Could you please guide me on how I post data in your SQL example and how I update data in the SQL example that you have in your github ? Thanks ! for example it is very useful. If you could kindly, provide one POST test case for that, it would really give me lot of clarity. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is no `eve.io.sqlalchemy` by looking at the [official source code of eve](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/tree/develop/eve/io). The Gist that you are looking at is a fork from eve but the changes are not pulled in yet officially.

See the [commit changes here](https://github.com/Tefnet/eve/commit/963769f1caacd9bda2937d0316cae14addbc110c).

Comment: what is data=SQLAlchemy?